# Find a normal subgroup of Dic6 of order 3

Tags: group-theory

How do i find a normal subgroup of Dic6 of order 3?
I can get the conjugacy classes and I know that a normal sungroup is a union of conjugacy classes. but do I go through them one by one?

If so, how do I show that there is no normal subgroup of order 8?

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that the dicyclic group $D$ is generated by an element $a$ of order $12$ and an element $x$ of order 4. By definition we have $a^x=a^{-1}$ so that $x \text{ acts on }a^4 \text{ as } a^8$ implying that the group $N = \langle  a^4 \rangle$ is normal. The quotient group is the quaternion group with $i = x$ and  $j = a^3$ (verify that $iji^{-1} = j^3$ and $i^2 = j ^2$. Conclude that $D$ is the semidirect product of N with the quaternion group. There are three quaternion groups the two others are obtained by replacing $i$ with $xa^4$ or with $xa^8$.